# Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(1)=0$. Show that supremum of $|x^nf(x)|$ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(1)=0$. Show that supremum of $|x^nf(x)|$ is zero as $n\to\infty$ for all $x\in[0,1]$?

My approach: Let $g(x)=x^nf(x)$. Then $g(1)=0$. Also $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, say by $M$. Then $|g(x)|\leq Mx^n$. Note that $x^n$ is decreasing over $[0,1)$. Hence $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So the supremum is zero. Am I correct?

Comment: In the future, if you prefer having your attempt evaluated *over* having the question answered, kindly use the [tag:solution-verification] tag. I might be nitpicky , but "Note that $x^n$ is decreasing over $[0,1)$. Hence $x^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$" would require a line or two more of explanation. The solution is fine otherwise.

Comment: Since this is as $n \to \infty$, should it be $\limsup$ rather than supremum?  But the argument for each point in  $[0,1)$ and for $1$ works for me,  You could turn it into a $\epsilon; n>N_\epsilon$ case quite easily

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will keep it mind in future.